# Point inside polygon -- json or kml?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to decide if I want to use json or kml to store polygons in a file on a server. I have to read in this file and check which polygon a given point is within. I am attracted to kml because I can render an entire kml file in two lines with the Google Maps Javascript API :

```
var importedKml = new google.maps.KmlLayer('mykml.kml'); 
importedKml.setMap(map);
```

However, I can't find a built-in function for checking if a point is inside all the polygons in a kml file. I know I can check to see if a point is in a polygon using the code below:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlngPoint, polygon);
```

but it looks as though I'd have to parse the kml and turn every

```
<Placemark><Polygon>
```

feature into a google.maps.polygon object first.

I've thought about going back to json, since json objects are extremely customizable and I could directly call something like

```
//json object polygonFile from server
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlngPoint, polygonFile.polygons[0].polygon);
```

with a structure I have built myself. There's no quick and easy way to render json to the map without first converting it to google maps objects and then rendeing those, though, it appears.

Is there a way to check if a point is within a polygon in a kml file *without* converting each feature to google maps objects first? If not, converting a json object to google maps objects sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

what about GEarthExtensions . There is a function "containsPoint" for an Polygon object
here is an example:
http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/source/browse/trunk/extensions/examples/point-in-poly.html